# How to delete an object in Unity in ExecuteInEditMode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

### What I am trying to do

I am trying to have one object with a serialized `int` that will spawn the number of objects I specify. When I change the number to a lower number, it should obviously delete and destroy the previous ones created.

This is causing an issue, however, do to the way `Update` works with `ExecuteInEditMode`, in that it gets executed whenever the scene gets changed, making this much harder.

### What I've tried

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Floor : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject gameObject;
    [SerializeField] bool shouldDestroy;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (shouldDestroy)
        {
            shouldDestroy = !shouldDestroy;
            gameObject.Destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Unreal Engine used this pattern a lot of having a visible `bool` that turns itself off and behaves more like a button in the editor, which came in handy. This would allow me to press `shouldDestroy` and destroy the object. Obviously, without the check, it would destroy `gameObject`, and `Update` is called again, it will destroy it again and so on.

I thought by added this boolean check, when `Update` was called again, it wouldn't do anything so the loop would stop, but nope, it continues and gets me an infinite loop.

I've also tried using a Coroutine, but that didn't fix anything.

**Is there any way to delete an object in `ExecuteInEditMode` without causing an infinite loop?** Maybe there's a better method than `Update` that doesn't update when *anything* in the scene changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

*GameObject.DestroyImmediate(gameObject);*

in Edit mode: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `DestroyImmediate()` in edit mode since `Destroy()` is delayed(delayed deconstruction will never be executed in edit mode).

unity docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html